# Using strategy passport paypal : failed to obtain access token

Tags: node.js, paypal, oauth, passport.js

With Passport (by Jared Hanson),

How can I use Paypal with openID or OAuth ?

I'm using passport-paypal-oauth strategy (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-paypal-oauth),

**NOTE :** my routes start with localhost:4000/api/users

- http://localhost:4000/api/users/signin/paypal
- http://localhost:4000/api/users/signin/paypal/callback

**My paypal endpoints :**

```
var passport_paypal = require('../middlewares/passport-paypal');

router.get('/signin/paypal', passport_paypal.authenticate('paypal-signin', {
scope: 'openid profile email'}));

router.get('/signin/paypal/callback', function(req, res, next){
passport_paypal.authenticate('paypal-signin', function(err, user, info){
    // Handle cases
    //return res.status(xxx).json('.. 
});
```

**My Paypal Strategies :**

```
var PaypalStrategy = require('passport-paypal-oauth').Strategy;

passport.use('paypal-signin', new PaypalStrategy({
clientID         : "MY APP ID",
clientSecret     : "MY APP SECRET",
callbackURL      : "http://localhost:4000/api/users/signin/paypal/callback",
tokenURL         : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
authorizationURL : "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize"

}, function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    !!!!! Not called ...

    // Get user profie
   // Save in db or other handling
}));
```

**Problem :** When I call http://localhost:4000/api/users/signin/paypal,
  I get the following answer in the browser :

```
 [InternalOAuthError: failed to obtain access token]
 name: 'InternalOAuthError',
 message: 'failed to obtain access token',
 oauthError:
 { statusCode: 400,
 data: '{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client credentials are missing"}' } }
```

And the `function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {` is never called.

**What is wrong ?**

---

I've already tested with  http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/users/signin/paypal

instead http://localhost:4000/api/users/signin/paypal

Comment: I the same problem, I try to use passport-paypal, passport-paypal-openidconnect and It doesn't work..

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your issue but callbackUrl should include http://localhost:4000

Comment: No Molda, my callbackURL already contains http://localhost:4000 : It's a problem about the passport strategy during Client credentials definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the one who forked and maintains the openid-connect package

the tokenURL should be the openidconnect url and not the oauth2 token url...

You can leave out the tokenURL and authorizationURL and just use sandbox: true (I can't speak for passport-paypal, I forgot if it has that built in too)

```
passport.use('paypal-signin', new PaypalStrategy({
  clientID         : "MY APP ID",
  clientSecret     : "MY APP SECRET",
  callbackURL      : "http://localhost:4000/api/users/signin/paypal/callback",
  sandbox: true
}, function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  // Get user profie
  // Save in db or other handling
  done(true);
}));
```

Comment: btw just in case people are wondering what's the correct url, openidconnect token should use `/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice` instead of `/v1/oauth2/token`

Comment: @dA3m0n ahh, but actually this really isnt the problem with the plugin, it is partly due to the documentations of paypal, oauth2 urls doesn't seem to work anymore, and openid-connect urls are not the old ones, the plugin works as long as the correct urls are used...

Comment: basically passport-paypal doesnt seem to work(i might be wrong, it didnt work for me, that's why i forked and wrote the "openidconnect" version), passport-paypal-openidconnect works, as long as you provide the correct urls(or you dont provide at all, default behavior would work, for sandbox, just provide "sandbox: true")

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it will resolve the problem, but the done function should be called in the callback with a true value if ok.

```
passport.use('paypal-signin', new PaypalStrategy({
clientID         : "MY APP ID",
clientSecret     : "MY APP SECRET",
callbackURL      : "http://localhost:4000/api/users/signin/paypal/callback",
tokenURL         : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
authorizationURL :   "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize"

 }, function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  // Get user profie
  // Save in db or other handling
  done(true);
 }));
```

Comment: this function is never called...it's the problem.